# WP Function to retrieve database connection

Tags: wordpress

Is there a function or command that pulls the db connection info from the WP blog? I am writing a Plugin which would have to connect to the db to retrieve the info, wondering if there was one single command/function i could call which could connect. this would make the plugin portable and would work on any WP blog. is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

See the [Interfacing with the Database](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class) docs.

You should just be able to use the global (curse you, Wordpress) variable `$wpdb` in your plugin functions, ie:

```
global $wpdb;
//do stuff
```

Plugins also have a few methods for storing "options" in the database.  I just found [this article](http://www.devlounge.net/code/wordpress-plugins-and-database-interaction), it details things fairly well.

Comment: Wordpress is all global variables unfortunately.  It causes a lot of problems if you get into anything more than the simplest custom development  :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create your own query with database then you can try this

```
require_once('wp-config.php'); 
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

You will get table prefix on **$table_prefix** this variable.
I think it will help you. For preview you can check my github repo https://github.com/webdeveloperkanai/flutter-wordpress-blog-view-app-full-setup

Thanks